# Can I get a function reference to a function with default parameters in Kotlin, as the parameterless function?

Tags: kotlin, function-reference

Is it possible to get a function reference to a function which has default parameters, specified as the parameterless call?

`InputStream.buffered()` is an extension method which transforms an `InputStream` into a `BufferedInputStream` with a buffer size of 8192 bytes.

```
public inline fun InputStream.buffered(bufferSize: Int = DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE): BufferedInputStream =
    if (this is BufferedInputStream) this else BufferedInputStream(this, bufferSize)
```

I would like to effectively reference the extension method, with the default parameters, and pass that to another function.

```
fun mvce() {
    val working: (InputStream) -> InputStream = { it.buffered() }

    val doesNotCompile: (InputStream) -> BufferedInputStream = InputStream::buffered
    val alsoDoesNotCompile: (InputStream) -> InputStream = InputStream::buffered
}
```

`doesNotCompile` and `alsoDoesNotCompile` produce the following error

> Type mismatch: inferred type is KFunction2 but (InputStream) -> BufferedInputStream was expected
>
> Type mismatch: inferred type is KFunction2 but (InputStream) -> InputStream was expected

I understand the error is because `InputStream.buffered()` isn't actually `(InputStream) -> BufferedInputStream`, but instead a shortcut for `(InputStream, Int) -> BufferedInputStream`, passing the buffer size as a parameter to the BufferedInputStream constructor.

The motivation is primarily style reasons, I'd rather use references that already exist, than create one at the last moment

```
val ideal: (InputStream) -> BufferedInputStream = InputStream::buffered// reference extension method with default parameter
val working: (InputStream) -> BufferedInputStream = { it.buffered() }// create new (InputStream) -> BufferedInputStream, which calls extension method
```

Comment: There is an issue about this [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8834).

Comment: I got it to work using `-XXLanguage:+NewInference` compiler argument as mentioned in that issue.

Comment: @gpunto want to make an answer so I can accept? Useful to know of the experimental tag, and the intention to be in a future version of Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [gpunto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292745/gpunto) and [Pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9241978/pawel) mentioned in the comments, using the `-XXLanguage:+NewInference` compiler argument allows function references with default values.

The issue is tracked [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8834), and is targeted for Kotlin 1.4.0.